# In a Select: How to get first row blank in result set followed by results

Tags: sql, excel, oracle

I have a query that when exported to excel requires that the first row has nothing in it. (a blank header if you will so the data starts on the second row)

How could I achieve this? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do a union all for all of your columns to get that blank row..

```
select null as col1,null as col2,.... null as coln from dual 
union all
select col1,col2,....coln from yourtable
```

You have to make sure that, the column aliases are the same for above two selects.

Comment: How do you (@cableload) and how did you (@user...) make sure that the FIRST row has all the nulls? Perhaps by simply relying on the accident of implementation that Oracle will not shuffle the rows? The definition (of relational databases, SQL, and Oracle) does not guarantee that result; you rely on it at your own peril.

Comment: good point @mathguy Perhaps the OP can use this [technique](http://blogs.uoregon.edu/developments/2010/12/13/add-an-empty-row-to-oracle-data-warehouse-query-results/) to always guarantee first row being blank

Comment: or we could use `select * from (select null as col1,null as col2,.... null as coln,0 as roworder from dual 
union all
select col1,col2,....coln,rownum as roworder from yourtable) order by roworder`

Answer (score 0):

The simplest would be just to add a blank row in Excel when you import it, however, if you ware trying to automate something, you could try something like this:

```
  select * from (
     select 0 rnum, 'header info here'  -- number of columns has to match your query below though
     from dual
     union all
     select row_number() over (order by ?? ) rnum,  -- put what order you want the data to come out as here
            a.*
       from ( your query goes here
            ) a
     )
  order by rnum
  /
```

You can programatically remove that first rnum column ...
Or change the outer `select *` to just be the columns you want.

Comment: If you want the columns to be blank, you probably want to select `NULL` on the first query of the union, for data type conformance.

Comment: Yeah, true, he did mention header, so I just providing a more generic option ... but yeah, it might make more sense to use NULL vs empty strings if he truly was a blank/empty line.

Comment: I'm not sure about oracle, but you might not be able to mix data types.  String literals probably show up as `varchar` or `nvarchar` by default, you might run into issues if you union that to a numeric or datetime type column.

Comment: agreed, I never mentioned mixing data types, but yeah, you may need to convert numbers to strings .. which isn't a big deal as this is going via a flat file to Excel anyway.

Comment: Yeah, I was having too many datatype mismatch issues so I went with the duplicate null union all query mentioned below.

Thank you very much for your suggestion and time.